# Processes involved to update an app

Tags: applications, updates, kiosk-mode

We run Android devices in KIOSK mode, and want users to able to update apps directly. Nothing happens when "Update" is clicked, it seems we need to whitelist / authorize some additional processes in KIOSK mode.

Could you please clarify what are the Android processes involved when an app is upgraded on a device ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you blacklist **Package Installer**?

Comment: No it's whitelisted (com.android.packageinstaller)

Comment: Are you updating your apps via the Play Store?

Comment: This is through the Mobile Iron app (Mobile@Work / Apps@Work) which is whitelisted in KIOSK mode